# Jitsi in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3, capacitor, jitsi-meet

How to use jitsi in Ionic?
I have tried following code to integrate jitsi in Ionic, but it gives me the following error when I build the Android app.
Also, I have tried using **capacitor-jitsi-meet** but couldn't succeed.

```
    import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
    import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
    import 'capacitor-jitsi-meet';
    const { Jitsi } = Plugins;
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: "app-jitsi-poc",
      templateUrl: "./jitsi-poc.page.html",
      styleUrls: ["./jitsi-poc.page.scss"],
    })
    export class JitsiPocPage implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild("videoConatiner") videoContainer: ElementRef;
      jitsi: any;
      options = {
        roomName: "my room ",
        configOverwrite: { startWithAudioMuted: true },
        interfaceConfigOverwrite: {
          SHOW_CHROME_EXTENSION_BANNER: false,
          SHOW_DEEP_LINKING_IMAGE: false,
          SHOW_JITSI_WATERMARK: false,
          SHOW_POWERED_BY: false,
          SHOW_PROMOTIONAL_CLOSE_PAGE: false,
          SHOW_BRAND_WATERMARK: false,
          JITSI_WATERMARK_LINK: "",
          SHOW_WATERMARK_FOR_GUESTS: false,
        },
      };
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() { }
    
      startMeeting() {
        this.options["parentNode"] = document.querySelector("#meet");
        // Setting parentNode option on init after the DOM has rendered
        this.jitsi = new (window as any).JitsiMeetExternalAPI("meet.jit.si", {
          ...this.options,
        }); // Jitsi running in local docker container
      }
    
    }
```

error

```
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    Could not find org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.5.0.
    Searched in the following locations:
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions to install Capacitor? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started

Next, I noticed you tried to activate the Jitsi web implementation, which won't work for native app implementation. The proper way of initiating a jitsi call on Android app is via the capacitor-jitsi-meet plugin, which is called using this syntax:

```
// On Capacitor 3
import { Jitsi } from 'capacitor-jitsi-meet';

// On Capacitor 1 and 2
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import 'capacitor-jitsi-meet';

const { Jitsi } = Plugins;

const result = await Jitsi.joinConference({
   roomName: 'room1', // room identifier for the conference
   url: 'https://meet.jit.si' // endpoint of the Jitsi Meet video bridge
});
```

Please see the readme for the full installation instructions: https://github.com/calvinckho/capacitor-jitsi-meet